# I connot able to filter the current user record using c# and MS Access DB

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access, join, error-handling

I connot able to filter the current user record. I want to display the data of current user only. But I did not understand how to handl query.
here is the ss of login.
[image]

As I selected Student, and username =50 and pass=50 ,

and when i press he show button this will display all the record but i want only current user data :
[image]

here is the code :

```
conn.Open();
                    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
                    cmd.Connection = conn;
                    OleDbDataAdapter sda = new OleDbDataAdapter(@"SELECT student.s_id, student.f_name, student.l_name, student.email, student.address, course.c_id, course.cname, resultdate.resultgrade FROM ((student INNER JOIN resultdate ON student.s_id = resultdate.s_id) INNER JOIN course ON resultdate.c_id = course.c_id)", conn);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                sda.Fill(dt);
                dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
                //dataGridView1.Text = dt.Rows.Count.ToString();
                conn.Close();
```

Comment: There's literally no "WHERE" clause in your query. You're not filtering at all.

Comment: when I filter my data using the where clause, data is not displayed.

`   OleDbDataAdapter sda = new OleDbDataAdapter(@"SELECT student.s_id, student.f_name, student.l_name, student.email, student.address, course.c_id, course.cname, resultdate.resultgrade FROM ((student INNER JOIN resultdate ON student.s_id = resultdate.s_id) INNER JOIN course ON resultdate.c_id = course.c_id) WHERE UserDetails.StudentId='"+comboBox1.Text+"' ", conn);`

Comment: @Nyerguds this show that " No value given for one or more required parameters"

Comment: Did you just copy-paste this code from somewhere? Do you actually know sql? You seem to have no idea how to properly construct queries. I'm fairly sure the check should be on `student.s_id`. And you should add parameters to a query as actual parameters, in code, not just added into the query text. And you need to give the argument in the correct type.

Comment: Dear @Nyerguds, I am using **student.s_id** because I am using JOINS. did you really know that, how joins works?

Answer (score 0):

Paste this code in your combobox.

```
        con.Open();

        string query = “ select* from student where student.s_id =  ’”
        +combobox1.SelectedItem.ToString() + “’”;
        OleDbDataAdapter sda = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, con);
        OleDbCommandBuiler builer = new OleDbCommandBuiler(da);
        var ds = new DataSet();
        sda.Fill(ds);
        datagridview1.Datasource = ds.Table[0];

        conn.Close();
```